# method with greater accessibility than class

Tags: c#, java

Is it reasonable to have method in sealed class with greater accessability than the class itself.
Of course just not taking into consideration later refactoring...

Example

```
class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In C# sealed isn't about access to the class but rather having the ability to inherit from it (i.e use it as a base class

Comment: In C#, the default class access modifier is `internal`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(My answer is for C# only)

Of course it can be useful!

**Reason 1:**

The access modifiers cannot all be put in order.

Would you say that `protected` was more accessable than `internal`, or less?

**Reason 2:**

Overriding bace class methods and implementing interfaces:

```
internal sealed class MyClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "How would you do this without public methods?";
    }
}
```

Now by casting a MyClass to Object, the method can be exposed outside the assembily.

This pattern is often used when implementing IEnumerator.  Often the real class will be private (not even internal).

**Reason 3:**

Access to a private nested class:

```
public class A
{
    public string TellMeWhy()
    {
        return B.TheReason;
    }

    sealed private class B
    {
        internal static string TheReason = 
            "How would you access any of these members " +
            "if they all have to be private?";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a reason to do that if the class implements an interface that is public. A factory (in the same package as SomeClass) could then instantiate the class and return it to users (that are using the interface)

Edit: My answer is in the context of how it works in Java.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common way of implementing a factory pattern ( I'm speaking from a java perspective here but I guess the same is true of c# )

Provide a public class with a public factory method returning instances of objects that implement a public interface.

Provide non-public implementations of the public interface that are returned by the factory.

Clients can get instances of the interface by calling the factory methid, but cannot instantiate them directly ( by using the `new` operator )

So, yes - it's a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

What would the use be? If you have no access to the class, how will you get access to the methods?

Don't know if it makes sense on a static class, but i doubt it.

Comment: Other classes in the same package have access to the class.

Comment: Via base classes or interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, 'no', largely on the grounds of KISS- don't code for things that you don't need.  If that method isn't needed outside the assembly, then make it internal.

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object.

So, it doesn't look very reasonable.

Comment: He doesn't have an inner and outer class. He has a class and a method.